# Difference between general-purpose operating systems and soft real time operating systems?

Tags: linux, embedded

What is the difference between general-purpose operating systems and "Soft" real time operating systems?

There is lots of confusion on the internet.

Can we say that a general-purpose OS is one type of soft RTOS?

And please no answer like "timing" and "deterministic time bound"

Thanks.

Comment: Not very helpful, but in my experience from the industry, "real time" is used to mean that a system is simply lacking in features, and "soft real-time" is used when the person who's saying it knows that the system does not actually have any real-time capabilities.

Comment: ok, but can i consider general purpose OS as Soft RTOS ?

Comment: You could, but you would be using the term in a technically wrong way (albeit in the same wrong way as many others use it). I'd recommend avoiding the term "real-time" unless you also clearly define what you mean by it, since it means different things to different people.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of a real-time OS is one which is guaranteed to perform a task before a certain amount of time has passed.

The terms "hard" and "soft" are no formally defined terms, but usually refer to the requirements of a real-time system task. If a task has "hard real-time" requirements, it must never fail to be done executing before its deadline. "Soft" requirements might mean that the task can execute beyond the given deadline, without causing any harm.

But sometimes the terms "hard" and "soft" could also refer to how tough the timing requirements are. For example, a realtime system which receives an interrupt it is supposed to handle every 100 microseconds, could be considered a "hard realtime" system.

I suspect the term "soft" is a marketing invention, where marketing people are trying to label systems that cannot guarantee real-time performance, as real-time systems. This has certainly been the case with many versions of Linux. The default desktop version of Linux is most certainly *not* a real-time OS.

Fluff terms like "hard" or "soft" don't really matter: either a system can guarantee execution before a deadline, or it cannot. Either it is a RTOS or it is not.

Comment: ok... So from u r point of view "Soft requirements might mean that the task can execute beyond the given deadline, without causing any harm." .. it is also happens with general purpose OS. if timing condition not meeting, no problem occurs.. [sorry for bad english] ..

Answer (score 0):

Soft RT linux kernel is usually ment the kernel with [RT preempt patch](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO) applied. It has a guaranties that it switch context within 10 ms.

Non-RT (or general) linux kernel is normal mainstream kernel, without RT patches applied.